# Why is git commit resulting in a detached HEAD?

Tags: git

I am running submodule update with merge flag to not end up in the detached HEAD state.

`git submodule update --init --force --remote --merge`

At this point `git status` returns `On branch master`

But after I run

`git commit -m "commit message"`

It says

```
[detached HEAD 0375093] commit message
 2 files changed, 89 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
```

Why is git commit resulting in a detached state?

Comment: check the output of `git status` within your submodule before you commit. Chances are you were already in a detached HEAD state.

Comment: I was in detached HEAD state but `git submodule update --init --force --remote --merge` should not result in detached HEAD state right?

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who had this issue, this is what I did to fix:

```
git add folder/file1.txt
git commit -m "made new changes"
git branch temp
git checkout master
git merge temp
git push origin master
git branch -D temp
```

After committing in the detached HEAD state you get an anonymous branch.
From here you can

- Create a temp branch
- Checkout out master
- Merged the temp branch(that contains the commit made in detached state) to master and push it to remote.
- Delete the temporary branch

Question still remains:
Why `git submodule update --init --force --remote --merge` is resulting in detached HEAD state?

Comment: "Question still remains: Why git submodule update --init --force --remote --merge is resulting in detached HEAD state?" Then don't put this into the Answer field, if it doesn't answer the question. Getting out of detached head is trivial and doesn't need an answer. Your question is how you got into detached head mode and this does not answer it.